# ffmpeg: unable to use hardware encoder h264_rkmpp with software decoded ATSC OTA transmission

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, mpeg-2

When attempting to hardware encode to h264 using the Rockchip MPP encoder h264_rkmpp from an ATSC source, FFMPEG errors out with:

"Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'"

The sample file used in this example can be downloaded here: https://transfer.sh/BRMej/out.ts

The full command used and resulting output is as follows:

```
$ ffmpeg -loglevel 48 -c:v mpeg2video -f mpegts -i out.ts -f mp4 -c:v h264_rkmpp -c:a libfdk_aac -preset ultrafast -mbd rd -copyinkf -flags +ilme+ildct -fflags +genpts out.mp4 -y

ffmpeg version N-98732-g9f702fc8f4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-rkmpp --enable-version3 --enable-libdrm --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavcodec     58.100.100 / 58.100.100
  libavformat    58. 51.100 / 58. 51.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100

Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '48'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'mpeg2video'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mpegts'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'out.ts'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mp4'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'h264_rkmpp'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libfdk_aac'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'ultrafast'.
Reading option '-mbd' ... matched as AVOption 'mbd' with argument 'rd'.
Reading option '-copyinkf' ... matched as option 'copyinkf' (copy initial non-keyframes) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-flags' ... matched as AVOption 'flags' with argument '+ilme+ildct'.
Reading option '-fflags' ... matched as AVOption 'fflags' with argument '+genpts'.
Reading option 'out.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 48.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url out.ts.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument mpeg2video.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mpegts.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: out.ts.
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] Opening 'out.ts' for reading
[file @ 0xaaaaec9ad830] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:5013504 seeks:1 nb_streams:0
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] stream=0 stream_type=0 pid=31 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] probing stream 0 pp:2500
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] Probe with size=204749, packets=1 detected mpegvideo with score=25
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] probed stream 0
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] stream=1 stream_type=0 pid=34 prog_reg_desc=
[mpeg2video @ 0xaaaaec9cb7d0] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] probing stream 1 pp:2500
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] Probe with size=7680, packets=1 detected ac3 with score=25
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] probed stream 1
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5005000 microseconds st:0
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 2632691898).
[mpegts @ 0xaaaaec9acf20] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:9195664 seeks:3 frames:306
Input #0, mpegts, from 'out.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:18.42, start: 29234.532200, bitrate: 5406 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x31], 152, 1/90000: Video: mpeg2video (Main), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(yuv420p) (tv, bt709, top first, left), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, Closed Captions, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 15000000/0/0 buffer size: 7995392 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1[0x34], 154, 1/90000: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url out.mp4.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mp4.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument h264_rkmpp.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument libfdk_aac.
Applying option copyinkf (copy initial non-keyframes) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: out.mp4.
Codec AVOption preset (Set the encoding preset (cf. x264 --fullhelp)) specified for output file #0 (out.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[file @ 0xaaaaec9cef20] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (h264_rkmpp))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[mpeg2video @ 0xaaaaec9cf7b0] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[mpeg2video @ 0xaaaaec9cf7b0] Skipping B slice due to open GOP
    Last message repeated 67 times
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[mpeg2video @ 0xaaaaec9cf7b0] Skipping B slice due to open GOP
    Last message repeated 67 times
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xaaaaecd8c290] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xaaaaecd8c290] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xaaaaecd8c290] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/90000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xaaaaecd8c290] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xaaaaecd8c290] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30000/1001'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xaaaaecd8c290] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:30000/1001 sar:1/1
[format @ 0xaaaaecadf950] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'drm_prime'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0xaaaaecd80070] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0xaaaaecd80070] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0xaaaaecadf950] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[AVIOContext @ 0xaaaaec9cf190] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0xaaaaec9b5900] Statistics: 9556112 bytes read, 3 seeks
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Did you patch ffmpeg to add h264_rkmpp encoder? Seems like your command is failing because of a missing `-vf hwupload` to convert the software AVFrame into a hardware format.